# trying to assign a variable in an if statement using buttons as the entrance condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code for trying to get the price of a venue:

```
# number of people
header = "Number of People"
people = ["10-25", "26-50", "51-100", "101-500", "501-1000", "1000+"]
button = buttonbox("around how many people will attend",title= header,choices=people)

# choosing the venue
if button == people[0]:
    button = "you chose '10-25'"
    header = "Recommended Venues"
    venueZero = ["your home, $0.00", "small garden, $20.00", "planetarium, $30.00"]
    button = buttonbox("Choose a venue",title= header,choices=venueZero)
```

and this is the code I'm using to try to assign a value to `venuePrice`:

```
if button == people[0] and button == venueZero[0]:
    venuePrice=4444
print venuePrice
```

However, when I print `venuePrice`, it says that it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

`button` can't equal both `people[0]` and `venueZero[0]` at the same time, therefore the condition in the if statement will never be met so `venuePrice` won't be set.

You could use a different variable name for the second choice:

```
# number of people
header = "Number of People"
people = ["10-25", "26-50", "51-100", "101-500", "501-1000", "1000+"]
button = buttonbox("around how many people will attend",title= header,choices=people)

# choosing the venue
if button == people[0]:
    button = "you chose '10-25'" # I don't understand the purpose of this statement but I'm not sure if you need it for anything so I'll leave it here.
    header = "Recommended Venues"
    venueZero = ["your home, $0.00", "small garden, $20.00", "planetarium, $30.00"]
    button2 = buttonbox("Choose a venue",title= header,choices=venueZero) # Changed from button to button2
```

Then change the if statement:

```
if button == people[0] and button2 == venueZero[0]:
    venuePrice=4444
print venuePrice
```

Comment: What you said is not technically true, as `button` could be a instance of a class defining a custom `__eq__` method.